# LaTeX: Specifying default document-wide font

Tags: fonts, latex

For some fonts, it's easy to replace the default font with something like: `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{somefont}`.

However, some fonts, like [BrushScriptX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/brushscriptx/)
want you to use a special command like `\bsifamily` to use the font. In the

`\bsifamily` is defined in /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/brushscr/pbsi.sty:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\bsifamily{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pbsi}%
  \fontseries{xl}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
```

In this case, I have a document that uses a cls stylesheet that I am editing. I'm using the standard includes to use this font:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}
```

If I try to use `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bpsi}` in my document's template, it fails with the error: Font shape `T1/pbsi/m/n' undefined

What might be the best way to replace the default roman font with BrushScriptX in a template, like `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{font}` would?

Comment: Answered on stack overflow (where you will find a bigger LaTeX community by far): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877597/how-do-you-change-the-document-font-in-latex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705532/latex-specifying-default-document-wide-font)